# Are Wikipedia and Wolfram Mathworld wrong about the CDF of the beta binomial?

Tags: probability, statistics, hypergeometric-function

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution) and [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaBinomialDistribution.html) claim that the CDF of the beta-binomial distribution is:
$$1- \tfrac{\mathrm{B}(\beta+n-k-1,\alpha+k+1)_3F_2(\boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{b};k)} {\mathrm{B}(\alpha,\beta)\mathrm{B}(n-k,k+2) (n+1)}$$ where $_3F_2(\boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{b};k)$ is the generalized hypergeometric function $$_3F_2(1,\! \alpha\! +\! k\!+ \! 1,k\! -\! n\! +\! 1;k\! +\! 2,k\! +\! 2\! -\! \beta\! -\! n;1)\!$$

This is dubious because $_3F_2(\cdot,\cdot,\cdot;\cdot,\cdot;1)$ is a [singularity](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/mpmath/functions/hypergeometric.html). Using Sympy, I evaluated that generalized hypergeometric function with the last argument changed to different values near $1$, and here's what I got:

```
In [5]: import mpmath as mp

In [7]: n = 1

In [8]: k = 1

In [9]: alpha = 1

In [10]: beta = 1

In [16]: spec = lambda alpha, beta, n, k: mp.hyp3f2(1, alpha + k + 1, k - n + 1, k + 2, k + 2 - beta 
    ...: - n, '1.0001')

In [17]: spec(alpha, beta, n, k)
Out[17]: mpf('-10000.0000000011')

In [18]: spec = lambda alpha, beta, n, k: mp.hyp3f2(1, alpha + k + 1, k - n + 1, k + 2, k + 2 - beta 
    ...: - n, '0.99999999')

In [19]: spec(alpha, beta, n, k)
Out[19]: mpf('99999999.497524068')
```

So it even changes sign. *What is the CDF of the beta binomial?*

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BetaBinomialDistribution.html says it is 1 for $k \ge n$

Answer (score 1):

Based on what gammatester said, I visited http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BetaBinomialDistribution.html. There the CDF is defined piecewise with the $k \geq n$ case being defined separately from the $0\leq k<n$ case. In particular, the GHGF should not be used when $k=n$. I edited the Wikipedia article to give the complete formula. That formula is
$$\Pr[K\leq k \mid n,\alpha,\beta]=\begin{cases} 0,& k < 0 \\ 1- \tfrac{\mathrm{B}(\beta+n-k-1,\alpha+k+1)_3F_2(\boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{b};k)} {\mathrm{B}(\alpha,\beta)\mathrm{B}(n-k,k+2) (n+1)}, & 0 \leq k < n \\ 1,& k \geq n \end{cases} $$

If $k$ is not an integer then it's necessary to replace $k$ with $\lfloor k \rfloor$ on the RHS.

---

The following is empirical evidence that the given formula works. It computes the survival function (i.e. $\Pr[K \geq k]$) instead of the CDF (i.e. $\Pr[K\leq k]$).

`python
import mpmath as mp
from scipy import *
from scipy.special import *
from sympy.functions import binomial`

## The clever formula using special functions

`python
def beta_binomial_survival_fn(alpha, beta, n, k):
    if k <= n:
        return exp(betaln(beta + n - k, alpha + k) + log(float(mp.hyp3f2(1, alpha + k, k - n, k + 1, k + 1 - beta - n, 1))) - betaln(alpha, beta) - betaln(n - k + 1, k + 1) - log(n+1))
    elif k > n:
        return 0
    elif k < 0:
        return 1
    else:
        raise ValueError("Can't compare k to n")`

## The less clever formula that sums the probability masses

`python
def beta_binomial_survival_fn_less_clever(alpha, beta, n, k):
    return sum(binomial(n, i) * exp(betaln(i+alpha, n-i+beta) - betaln(alpha,beta)) for i in range(k, n+1))`

## The following computes the maximum error in using the clever formula in place of the not-so-clever formula

`python
max(abs(beta_binomial_survival_fn(alpha, beta, n, k) - beta_binomial_survival_fn_less_clever(alpha, beta, n, k)) for alpha in range(1,6) for beta in range(1,6) for n in range(1,6) for k in range(0,6))`

```
8.88178419700125e-16
```

Comment: You deem the use of generalized hypergeometric function more clever. Does the cleverness stem from the accuracy or speed of the computation or just that it makes the connection between a special function and the beta-binomial distribution?

Comment: @Hans It's usually considered better to work with log probabilities instead of probabilities, because adding log probabilities incurs less approximation error than multiplying probabilities. The survival function $\Pr[K \geq k]$ is a product and doesn't involve any addition, so it's especially nice to take the log. It happens to involve a GHGF, but not one that takes especially extreme values.

Comment: I see. Can you provide some references for your assertion "adding log probabilities incurs less approximation error than multiplying probabilities"?

Comment: @Hans No, the best I can do is Google "log probability". A lot of what comes up says that log representation helps against numerical underflow. I'm actually finding that the *clever* formula gives approximately the same results as the *non-clever* formula, suggesting that you *can* simply take the $log$ after using the non-clever formula. At the very least, my answer confirms that the latest formula on Wikipedia is now correct.

Comment: OK. It makes sense to use logarithm against numerical underflow.